# equation exceeds the page border

Tags: equations

I have the following equation which goes behind the page border:

```
\begin{equation}
P(word|name_i)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^{2}}} \times exp^{\frac{-(tf(name_i,word)*idf(name_i,word)-\mu_i)^{2}}{2\sigma_i^{2}}}
\end{equation}
```

is there anyway to prevent this to happen?

**EDIT**

here is the MWE. please note that for the document class, you should download the template from [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates).

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P(word|name_i)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^{2}}} \times exp^{\frac{-(tf(name_i,word)*idf(name_i,word)-\mu_i)^{2}}{2\sigma_i^{2}}}
\end{equation

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Behind"? Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Werner i dont know how to but i am using `\documentclass{sig-alternate}` and for this equation, when I run to get the pdf fprmat, the equaton goes from first column into second column, maybe because it is too long, so i wonder if there is some way to force it to be auto adjust to only its column?

Comment: @Werner i made a mistake and put a wrong equation. i made an edit and now that equation makes the problem

Comment: @Nasser how about the **EDIT** now?

Comment: @Nasser did you read the text above the code? you need to download the template from http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `multline` environment from `amsmath` for this.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\label{eq:likelihood}
P(Keyword\mid Seg_i)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^{2}}}\\
 \times\exp^{\frac{-(tf(Seg_i,Keyword)*idf(Seg_i,Keyword)-\mu_i)^{2}}{2\sigma_i^{2}}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

I don't know what `tf` and `idf` are, but if they are meant to be operators, it is better to define

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\idf}{idf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tf}{tf}
```

Also, probably, many words have to be typeset as text.

MWE

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\idf}{idf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tf}{tf}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\label{eq:likelihood}
P(\text{Keyword}\mid\text{Seg}_i)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^{2}}}\\
 \times\exp^{\frac{-(\tf(\text{Seg}_i,\text{Keyword})*\idf(\text{Seg}_i,\text{Keyword})-\mu_i)^{2}}{2\sigma_i^{2}}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want to fit it in one line, use `\resizebox` from `graphicx`

MWE

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator{\idf}{idf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tf}{tf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:likelihood}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle
P(\text{Keyword}\mid\text{Seg}_i)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^{2}}}
 \times\exp^{\frac{-(\tf(\text{Seg}_i,\text{Keyword})*\idf(\text{Seg}_i,\text{Keyword})-\mu_i)^{2}}{2\sigma_i^{2}}}
$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

BTW: You should use `e^{...}` or `\exp(....)` instead of `\exp^(....)`, as Mico suggests in his comment.

Comment: that is nice, but is there any way to fit whole equation in one line? i mean, something like changing the font size so that fit into one line?

Comment: @user1064929 Yes, see the last part of the answer.

Comment: great! that is what looks nicer

Comment: Another comment, related to exponential notation: In general, I think that one should write either `e^{...}` or `\exp(....)`, but not `\exp^{...}`.

Comment: @Mico Of course you're right (as always). Added in the answer.

Comment: well, i prefer the first one , `e^{}` which looks more accurate, i mean the second notation looks like that `exp` function is in front of the numerator while it should be in front of the whole fraction. anyhow, i changed it to `e^{}` and thanks for the suggestion.